# Converting JSON output from API pull to pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping

I am using an API pull to extract data from the AESO API in python. My code is as follows:

```py
API_KEY = 'api_key_here'

merit_order_url = 'https://api.aeso.ca/report/v1/meteredvolume/details?startDate=2022-01-01'

url = merit_order_url

headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'X-API-Key': API_KEY}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The JSON response looks something like this:

```json
{'timestamp': '2023-08-10 14:07:24.976+0000',
 'responseCode': '200',
 'return': [{'pool_participant_ID': '9496',
   'asset_list': [{'asset_ID': '941A',
     'asset_class': 'RETAILER',
     'metered_volume_list': [{'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 07:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 00:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005865'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 08:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 01:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005363'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 09:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 02:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005209'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 10:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 03:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005171'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 11:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 04:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005152'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 12:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 05:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005104'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 13:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 06:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005164'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 14:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 07:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005426'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 15:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 08:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005907'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 16:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 09:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006283'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 17:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 10:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006528'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 18:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 11:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0007141'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 19:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 12:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0007192'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 20:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 13:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0007495'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 21:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 14:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006842'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 22:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 15:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006804'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 23:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 16:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0007282'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 00:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 17:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0008322'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 01:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 18:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0008516'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 02:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 19:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0007729'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 03:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 20:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006861'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 04:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 21:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006861'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 05:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 22:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0006434'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 06:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 23:00',
       'metered_volume': '0.0005783'}]},
    {'asset_ID': '941C',
     'asset_class': 'RETAILER',
     'metered_volume_list': [{'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 07:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 00:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 08:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 01:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 09:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 02:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 10:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 03:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 11:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 04:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 12:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 05:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 13:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 06:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 14:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 07:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 15:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 08:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 16:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 09:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 17:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 10:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 18:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 11:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 19:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 12:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 20:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 13:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 21:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 14:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 22:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 15:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-01 23:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 16:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 00:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 17:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 01:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 18:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 02:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 19:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 03:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 20:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 04:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 21:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 05:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 22:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'},
      {'begin_date_utc': '2022-01-02 06:00',
       'begin_date_mpt': '2022-01-01 23:00',
       'metered_volume': '0'}]},
```

When I use the following code:

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(df['return'])
```

The dataset looks like the following:

[image]

I would like to convert the asset_list column into its own dataframe. Where `asset_ID`, `asset_class`, `begin_date_utc`, `begin_date_mpt and` metered_volume` are column. How would I go about this?

Comment: hi @user17059762! any chance you could include the data itself, instead of a picture of it? e.g. copy and paste the json

Answer (score 3):

Using [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) You need to map the levels in meta and record_path:

Code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=[
        ["return", "pool_participant_ID"],
        ["return", "asset_list", "asset_ID"],
        ["return", "asset_list", "asset_class"],
    ],
    record_path=["return", "asset_list", "metered_volume_list"]
).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      begin_date_utc    begin_date_mpt metered_volume pool_participant_ID asset_ID asset_class
0   2022-01-01 07:00  2022-01-01 00:00      0.0005865                9496     941A    RETAILER
1   2022-01-01 08:00  2022-01-01 01:00      0.0005363                9496     941A    RETAILER
2   2022-01-01 09:00  2022-01-01 02:00      0.0005209                9496     941A    RETAILER
3   2022-01-01 10:00  2022-01-01 03:00      0.0005171                9496     941A    RETAILER
4   2022-01-01 11:00  2022-01-01 04:00      0.0005152                9496     941A    RETAILER
5   2022-01-01 12:00  2022-01-01 05:00      0.0005104                9496     941A    RETAILER
6   2022-01-01 13:00  2022-01-01 06:00      0.0005164                9496     941A    RETAILER
7   2022-01-01 14:00  2022-01-01 07:00      0.0005426                9496     941A    RETAILER
8   2022-01-01 15:00  2022-01-01 08:00      0.0005907                9496     941A    RETAILER
9   2022-01-01 16:00  2022-01-01 09:00      0.0006283                9496     941A    RETAILER
10  2022-01-01 17:00  2022-01-01 10:00      0.0006528                9496     941A    RETAILER
11  2022-01-01 18:00  2022-01-01 11:00      0.0007141                9496     941A    RETAILER
12  2022-01-01 19:00  2022-01-01 12:00      0.0007192                9496     941A    RETAILER
13  2022-01-01 20:00  2022-01-01 13:00      0.0007495                9496     941A    RETAILER
14  2022-01-01 21:00  2022-01-01 14:00      0.0006842                9496     941A    RETAILER
15  2022-01-01 22:00  2022-01-01 15:00      0.0006804                9496     941A    RETAILER
16  2022-01-01 23:00  2022-01-01 16:00      0.0007282                9496     941A    RETAILER
17  2022-01-02 00:00  2022-01-01 17:00      0.0008322                9496     941A    RETAILER
18  2022-01-02 01:00  2022-01-01 18:00      0.0008516                9496     941A    RETAILER
19  2022-01-02 02:00  2022-01-01 19:00      0.0007729                9496     941A    RETAILER
20  2022-01-02 03:00  2022-01-01 20:00      0.0006861                9496     941A    RETAILER
21  2022-01-02 04:00  2022-01-01 21:00      0.0006861                9496     941A    RETAILER
22  2022-01-02 05:00  2022-01-01 22:00      0.0006434                9496     941A    RETAILER
23  2022-01-02 06:00  2022-01-01 23:00      0.0005783                9496     941A    RETAILER
24  2022-01-01 07:00  2022-01-01 00:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
25  2022-01-01 08:00  2022-01-01 01:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
26  2022-01-01 09:00  2022-01-01 02:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
27  2022-01-01 10:00  2022-01-01 03:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
28  2022-01-01 11:00  2022-01-01 04:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
29  2022-01-01 12:00  2022-01-01 05:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
30  2022-01-01 13:00  2022-01-01 06:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
31  2022-01-01 14:00  2022-01-01 07:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
32  2022-01-01 15:00  2022-01-01 08:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
33  2022-01-01 16:00  2022-01-01 09:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
34  2022-01-01 17:00  2022-01-01 10:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
35  2022-01-01 18:00  2022-01-01 11:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
36  2022-01-01 19:00  2022-01-01 12:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
37  2022-01-01 20:00  2022-01-01 13:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
38  2022-01-01 21:00  2022-01-01 14:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
39  2022-01-01 22:00  2022-01-01 15:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
40  2022-01-01 23:00  2022-01-01 16:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
41  2022-01-02 00:00  2022-01-01 17:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
42  2022-01-02 01:00  2022-01-01 18:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
43  2022-01-02 02:00  2022-01-01 19:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
44  2022-01-02 03:00  2022-01-01 20:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
45  2022-01-02 04:00  2022-01-01 21:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
46  2022-01-02 05:00  2022-01-01 22:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
47  2022-01-02 06:00  2022-01-01 23:00              0                9496     941C    RETAILER
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this. Use `explode` for the list and use `json_normalize` again on the nested object.

```
df = (pd.json_normalize(df['return'], record_path=['asset_list'])
      .explode('metered_volume_list'))

df = pd.concat([df[['asset_ID', 'asset_class']].reset_index(drop=True), 
                pd.json_normalize(df.metered_volume_list)], axis=1)
```